# Define method with closure in an @objc protocol

Tags: objective-c, swift, closures

I have the following protocol definition:

```
@objc protocol PersonDataStore {

    func findPersonWithId(remoteId: String, completionBlock: ((Person) -> Void)!)
    // ...
}
```

The error I get is that the second parameter cannot be represented in Objective-C. I researched the blocks/closures topic but I have a hard time getting my head around it since it is so conceptually different.

Is this just a matter of syntax or is it really not possible to define an Objective-C protocol with a closure in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is that your class `Person` is not a subclass of `NSObject`.  Add `@objc` to the declaration of your `Person` class or make it a subclass of `NSObject` and your protocol definition should work.

Comment: Absolutely correct, I just found out the same. Thank you very much!